# Using AWS and trying to track usage costs to specific groups under one organization account ID

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have specific groups within our organization. We have one AWS account for our organization in which we are billed to, however we have specific groups within our organization in which we need to bill based on the resources used. We are trying to tie a group name to all of the AWS services used for that particular group. We have been looking at the various canned reports as well as the cost and usage report but cannot seem to tie the cost reports back to the individual groups. There are many line items on the cost reports which just show usage without any id that we can use or name to track it to the users. Has anyone had this type of problem and found a way to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [cost allocation tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html). More info [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/tags-billing-cost-center-project/). The tricky part is getting all your resources tagged, and some things can't be tagged like bandwidth.

A more common approach is to have one account per group / project. We typically do one account per application per environment, so if we have dev, test and prod for apps 1, 2, 3, and 4 we have 12 accounts. It's fairly easy to manage with AWS Organisations, and it reduces the blast radius - if something goes wrong it doesn't take down everything. You do end up paying more for inter-account bandwidth though.

Comment: Thanks!  Those are some great ideas.

Comment: Welcome. If you're happy with the answer now or later please accept it, as that way others don't need to come read the question trying to help.